# JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX environment variable is empty when submitting an Indexed Job to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I've made my cluster using minukube.

as I know, Indexed-Job feature is added at kubernetes version [1.21](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-1-21-whats-new/).

but when I made my job, it looks like there is no $JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX environ variable.

here is my yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job
spec:
  parallelism: 2
  completions: 2
  completionMode: Indexed
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: 'my-container'
        image: 'busybox'
        command: [
          "sh",
          "-c",
          "echo My Index is $JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX && sleep 3600",
        ]
```

```sh
$ job.batch/my-job created
```

but as I mentioned before, it looks like the job is **NOT Indexed-Job**

below is logs of my pods(controlled by my-job)

```
$ kubectl logs pod/my-job-wxhh6
My Index is
$ kubectl logs pod/my-job-nbxkr
My Index is
```

It seems that the **$JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX** environ variable is empty.

I'll skip it to make it brief, but when I directly accessed the container, there is also no $JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX.

and below is result of `kubectl describe job.batch/my-job`  command

```
Name:           my-job
Namespace:      default
Selector:       controller-uid=6e8bda0c-f1ee-47b9-95ec-87419b3dfaaf
Labels:         controller-uid=6e8bda0c-f1ee-47b9-95ec-87419b3dfaaf
                job-name=my-job
Annotations:    <none>
Parallelism:    2
Completions:    2
Start Time:     Sat, 28 Aug 2021 03:56:46 +0900
Pods Statuses:  2 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=6e8bda0c-f1ee-47b9-95ec-87419b3dfaaf
           job-name=my-job
  Containers:
   my-container:
    Image:      busybox
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      echo My Index is $JOB_COMPLETION_INDEX && sleep 3600
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  100s  job-controller  Created pod: my-job-wxhh6
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  100s  job-controller  Created pod: my-job-nbxkr
```

there is no annotation. [as document](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/19/introducing-indexed-jobs/), `batch.kubernetes.io/job-completion-index` annotation must be there.

My version is upper than kubernetes [1.21](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-1-21-whats-new/), where the Indexed-Job feature is introduced.

```sh
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
$ minukube kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

as of now(2021.08.29), the **IndexedJob** is an alpha feature, so I started minikube with feature-gates flag

```
minikube start --feature-gates=IndexedJob=true
```

and It works well

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is incorrect; you need to be on the rapid release channel, at least version 1.22.